# How to traverse an SVG as a tree structure with SnapSVG?

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I'm trying [SnapSVG](http://snapsvg.io) and some common tasks are easy to perform with it.
However, I can't seem to figure out how to traverse an SVG file as a tree structure. From what I can gather in the documentation `select()` and `selectAll()` which either select a single element or collapses groups.

I'm using bunch of groups that look like this:

```
<g id="FC1">
    <g id="S2B" class="st0">
        <path class="st1" d="M779.838,895.4v43.897h-70.5V895.4H779.838z M709.339,895.4"></path>
        <path class="st1" d="M922.14,895.4h70.5v43.897h-70.5V895.4z M922.14,939.297"></path>
        <path class="st1" d="M567.471,939.297V895.4h70.5v43.897H567.471z M637.97,939.297"></path>
        <path class="st1" d="M993.074,895.4h70.5v43.897h-70.5V895.4z M993.074,939.297"></path>
        <path class="st1" d="M921.706,895.4v43.897h-70.5V895.4H921.706z M851.206,895.4"></path>
        <path class="st1" d="M638.405,895.4h70.5v43.897h-70.5V895.4z M638.405,939.297"></path>
        <path class="st1" d="M1064.008,895.4h70.5v43.897h-70.5V895.4z M1064.008,939.297"></path>
        <path class="st1" d="M780.272,939.297V895.4h70.5v43.897H780.272z M850.772,939.297"></path>
    </g>
    <g id="S2A" class="st0">
        <path class="st1" d="M1418.243,939.297h-70.5V895.4h70.5V939.297z M1418.243,895.4"></path>
        <path class="st1" d="M1489.611,895.4h70.5v43.897h-70.5V895.4z M1489.611,939.297"></path>
        <path class="st1" d="M1418.677,939.297V895.4h70.5v43.897H1418.677z M1489.177,939.297"></path>
        <path class="st1" d="M1205.441,939.297h-70.5V895.4h70.5V939.297z M1205.441,895.4"></path>
        <path class="st1" d="M1560.545,895.4h70.5v43.897h-70.5V895.4z M1560.545,939.297"></path>
        <path class="st1" d="M1347.309,895.4v43.897h-70.5V895.4H1347.309z M1276.809,895.4"></path>
        <path class="st1" d="M1772.912,895.4v43.897h-70.5V895.4H1772.912z M1702.413,895.4"></path>
        <path class="st1" d="M1773.346,895.4h70.5v43.897h-70.5V895.4z M1773.346,939.297"></path>
        <path class="st1" d="M1914.78,939.297h-70.5V895.4h70.5V939.297z M1914.78,895.4"></path>
        <path class="st1" d="M1701.978,939.297h-70.5V895.4h70.5V939.297z M1701.978,895.4"></path>
        <path class="st1" d="M1276.375,939.297h-70.5V895.4h70.5V939.297z M1276.375,895.4"></path>
    </g>
    <g id="S2C" class="st0">
        <path class="st1" d="M283.735,939.297V895.4h70.5v43.897H283.735z M354.235,939.297"></path>
        <path class="st1" d="M496.537,939.297V895.4h70.5v43.897H496.537z M567.037,939.297"></path>
        <path class="st1" d="M425.169,939.297h-70.5V895.4h70.5V939.297z M425.169,895.4"></path>
        <path class="st1" d="M496.103,939.297h-70.499V895.4h70.499V939.297z M496.103,895.4"></path>
    </g>
</g>
```

If I do `select("g)` this hierarchy is collapsed.

I can use plain JS and `document.querySelector()` to access elements, but I was hoping to use some of SnapSVG's features.

What is the recommended way to traverse a tree hierarchy with SnapSVG ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

selectAll() with a forEach() would be my normal way...you can combine them as well,

So Snap('#FC1') or Snap('g') selects the first g element
or you can use paper.select('#FC1') if you already have an svg/group element. You can then use select/selectAll on that element (as long as its a container element like g/svg).

You can combine, for example...

```
paper.select('g').selectAll('g').forEach( doSomethingFunc )
```

This would select the first g element, and then select all of the g elements inside the first g element.

When you use Snap( selector ) or selectAll type thing, behind the scenes its using a css querySelectorAll, so you can think of them similar.

For example, if you had several nested 'g's, you could use a css selector to specify the first level, parse through that, and act on them...eg

```
var gs3 = s.selectAll('svg>g').forEach ( selectNext )

function selectNext( el ) {
  var els = el.selectAll('g>g'); // do children
  console.log( els )
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j3h0jttm/2/)

Or if you want, you can access the DOM directly, with something like

```
el.node.children
```

And reference them, you can alwaya 'Snapify' them to use Snap again with Snap(DOMelement) as you loop through them.

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful (+1). If I access #FC1, I select the groups within. The issue I'm having is looping through a buch of #FC prefixed layers which are at the root of the document. Is there any ```children()``` method or something similar that will allow me to list elements in a node one level at a time ? It feels hacky to loop through all the groups, check if the id starts with FC, and if so, treat them differently from the nested S-prefixed groups.

Comment: I've added a bit more info to the end, see if that helps at all.

Comment: Sweeeet! I had no idea about using ```>``` when querying SVG. Thanks Ian, that's bang on the buck!

Comment: Another quick one on the topic: If don't think I fully undetstood the ">" notation. Let's say I have  anode like this: ```<g id="FC5">
 <g id="S9-S10">
  <g id="S10" class="st0">
   <path class="st1" d="M870.252,528.775h-7.754v-4.828h7.754V528.775z"/>
  </g>
  <g id="S9" class="st0">
   <path class="st1" d="M901.46,533.658h-7.754v-4.828h7.754V533.658z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
 <g id="S11-S12">
 </g>
</g>``` how do I access the S9-S10 and S11-S12 without having their children in the same set ?

Comment: I did try that, but I get a collapsed list (S9-S10, S9, S10, S11-S12, S11, S12). What I'd like to do is loop through FC5's children (S9-S10, S11-S12), then iterate through each of their children (S9,S10), then (S11,S12) separately.

Comment: What I tried is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/orgicus/j3h0jttm/6/). This is starting to make more sense. ' > ' goes a level deeper and 'g' is the group selector.